# std::atomic not supported by clang?

Tags: c++, clang, atomic, stdatomic

I am trying to use std::atomic with clang. However, whenever I try to include the header file atomic (`#include <atomic>`), I get the message "atomic not found". Note that I'm including -`std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` while compiling. What am I missing?

The version of clang I'm using is 3.2.

Comment: What version of clang do you have?

Comment: This is more about which standard library implementation do you use? Which version is it? You can change it with the option `-stdlib=<value>`.

Comment: [Works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10d0767a56a897d8) on clang 3.4. You may have to upgrade.

Comment: I tried to use std=c++0x but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

> The version of clang I'm using is 3.2.

Clang added atomic support across two different versions according to [LLVM CXX Status](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html). The first was Clang 3.1, and the second was Clang 3.2.

I *think* you can check for it using:

```
#if defined(__clang__)
#  if __has_feature(cxx_atomic)
#    define CLANG_CXX11_ATOMICS 1
#  endif
#endif
```

Then, in your code:

```
#if CLANG_CXX11_ATOMICS
# include <atomic>
#endif

...

#if defined(CLANG_CXX11_ATOMICS)
# define MEMORY_BARRIER() std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel)
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
# define MEMORY_BARRIER() __asm__ __volatile__ ("" ::: "memory")
...
#endif
```

I can only say *"I think"* because `cxx_atomic` is *not* documented at [Clang Language Extensions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html). However, it shows up on a search of the LLVM site: ["cxx_atomic" site:llvm.org](http://www.google.com/search?q="cxx_atomic"+site:llvm.org).

There's also an open question of the CFE Users mailing list: [How to check for std::atomic availability?](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-users/2016-May/000938.html)

---

> Note that I'm including -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ while compiling. What am I missing?

For this, you might be using one of those Clang/LLVM C++ runtimes that's really just C++03, but pretends to be C++11. It caused me a lot of problems in the past because we support a number of compilers and platforms.

[Below is a test Jonathan Wakely helped us craft](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/config.h#L643) to see if it really was a C++11 library, or one of Apple's fake C++11 libraries:

```
// Visual Studio began at VS2010, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.
// Intel and C++11 language features, http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler
// GCC and C++11 language features, http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html
// Clang and C++11 language features, http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html
#if (_MSC_VER >= 1600) || (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
# define CXX11_AVAILABLE 1
#endif

// Hack ahead. Apple's standard library does not have C++'s unique_ptr in C++11. We can't
//   test for unique_ptr directly because some of the non-Apple Clangs on OS X fail the same
//   way. However, modern standard libraries have <forward_list>, so we test for it instead.
//   Thanks to Jonathan Wakely for devising the clever test for modern/ancient versions.
// TODO: test under Xcode 3, where g++ is really g++.
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__clang__)
#  if !(defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<forward_list>))
#    undef CXX11_AVAILABLE
#  endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify `-I /path/to/your/c++` (or, almost equivalently, `-cxx-isystem /path/to/your/c++`) so that `clang++` can find its location?

If you think you should not need them, please try `clang++ -print-search-dirs` to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of clang is outdated. You should grab the last version, either from your package manager or from http://clang.llvm.org/.

Comment: I don't want to upgrade right now. Do you know of anything that works with the version 3.2? I tried -std=c++0x but that also didn't work.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Just upgrade your libc++?